# "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: _this.setState is not a function" error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I try to load new data everytime user scrolled pass the waypoint.
however when axios try to fetch the data, i'm getting this error which i have no idea where is wrong eventhough i have gone through numerous posts.

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: _this.setState is not a function
```

below is my code, appreciate some advice, thanks.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Waypoint } from 'react-waypoint';


export class PostIndex extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        page: 1,
        posts: [],
    };
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.getPosts();
}

getPosts = () => {
    axios.get('/api/posts', {params: {page: this.state.page}})
    .then(response => { 
        this.setState({
          posts: response.data.posts
        });
    })

    this.setState = ({ page: this.state.page += 1 });
}



render () {

    return (
        <div>
            <p> i am post index </p>
            <section>
            <div style={{height: 1500}} />
              <Waypoint
                onEnter={this.getPosts}
              />
            </section>
        </div>
    );
}

}

export default PostIndex;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this

```
this.setState = ({ page: this.state.page += 1 });
```

into

```
 this.setState({ page: this.state.page += 1 });
```

Comment: thanks, really stupid mistake from my side, thanks.